# Merge two data Frame if data from one column is present in another column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two excel files.

```
Excel 1 - a.xlsx containing
SL NO       Fruit   Colour  Quantity
1           Apple       
2           Orange      
3           Banana      
4           Pineapple       
5           pears       
6           Grape       
7           Mango
```

and Excel 2 - b.xlsx containing

```
SL NO       Fruit       Colour      Quantity
1           Apple       RED         2
2           Orange      Orange      4
3           Pineapple   Brown       6
4           Grape       Purple      8
```

I want a new excel file which is complete like this

```
SL NO       Fruit       Colour      Quantity
1           Apple       RED         2
2           Orange      Orange      4
3           Banana      
4           Pineapple   Brown       6
5           pears       
6           Grape       Purple      8
7           Mango
```

How do I perform the same? The matching should be done based on the fruit name. I am able to load it into different data frames, but how do I operate after that and create a new excel with the merged output?
I am new to python and I am learning, so any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set `Fruit` as the index in both the dataframes, then use reindex on the second dataframe (from `b.xlsx`) with the index of the first dataframe(from `a.xlsx`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to install the pandas library. If you don't have it yet, use:

```
pip install pandas
```

Now, import pandas and you can use pd.merge function:

```
import pandas as pd

new_excel = pd.merge(excel_1, excel_2, on = ['Fruit'], how = 'left')
```

This is going to be similar to a VLOOKUP function in excel if that helps you understand. If it's of your interest, check out this post to learn more:  [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)